# Push input to array and clear input not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have a controller which fetches data from a factory, as follows:

```
.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Messages) {
  $scope.messages = Messages.get($stateParams.partnerId);
  $scope.send = function (input) {
    input.id = Math.random();
    input.sent = true;
    input.time = new Date();
    $scope.messages.data.push(input);
    console.log($scope.messages);
  }
})
```

I use an ng-repeat to display the messages on the template. I then have an input which uses ng-click to run send. The problem is, when you send it then its added to the array, however if you carry on typing then it updates the sent message, rather than allowing you to send a new one.

How can I pass the input to the array, in a way which allows me to repeat it many times?

Comment: how about you add `input = {}` after you pushed it?

Comment: That doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Maybe also post the template to make more clear what it is about.

The Problem is that by pushing `input` into the Array, you still keep a reference inside your model (`$scope`), you dont refresh it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [angular.copy](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) so that you are not pushing the same reference but an entirely new object similar to input

```
.controller('ChatDetailCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams, Messages) {
  $scope.messages = Messages.get($stateParams.partnerId);
  $scope.send = function (input) {
    input.id = Math.random();
    input.sent = true;
    input.time = new Date();
    $scope.messages.data.push(angular.copy(input));
    console.log($scope.messages);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having seen your markup and/or the structure of `input`, this here does the trick:

JsBin: http://jsbin.com/xevabevi/10/edit

Like Charminbear said, you need to clear the input data some way, after pushing to the messages array.

Alternatively, you could do the following in the push:

```
$scope.arr.push(angular.copy(input));
```

That way you wouldn't push the input data to the array, rather you would push a copy of it. This wouldn't clear your input fields however, as the original `input` would stay intact.